# SSRS Interactive Sort Row Group data by Column Group

Tags: sorting, reporting-services, row, interactive

In SSRS I am attempting to do an interactive sort on the combination of a column group and a row group.

So my data would look like:

```
    -------- ------------- --------- -------- -----------------
    Category  CampaignType  Campaign  Quarter Value   
    -------- ------------- --------- -------- -----------------
    Cat 1     CampType1     Camp1     Q1      1
    Cat 1     CampType1     Camp1     Q2      4
    Cat 1     CampType1     Camp2     Q1      51 
    Cat 1     CampType2     Camp1     Q1      3 
    Cat 1     CampType2     Camp1     Q2      1  
    Cat 1     CampType2     Camp2     Q1      3 
    Cat 1     CampType2     Camp2     Q3      56 
    Cat 2     CampType1     Camp1     Q1      8 
    Cat 2     CampType1     Camp1     Q3      11 
    Cat 2     CampType1     Camp2     Q1      2
    Cat 2     CampType2     Camp1     Q1      23 
    Cat 2     CampType2     Camp2     Q1      3 
    Cat 2     CampType3     Camp2     Q2      8 
    -------- ------------- --------- -------- -----------------
```

So I am grouping on the rows by:

-Category  
 ---CampType 
 ------Campaign

Grouping on the column by the row. 
Getting the sum of the "Value" at the intersection of these two points.  
Add some totals and we're done.

I would like to be able to sort the campaign value sums by quarter.  
That, in my opinion seems like a reasonable request.

See below firstly what it looks like in designer and then an example:

[image: The report in the designer]
[image: An example - please excuse the dodgy ms paint live data removal]

Comment: Gah! I'm fairly certain this isn't possible now due to lack of response.

Comment: I'm having the same issue at the moment and cannot find a configuration that works. Is there anyone that can confirm if this is even possible?

Comment: Have the same problem, anybody have the solution?

Comment: What if you did the sum in your SQL?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx